# Lower limit topology on $\mathbb R$ is regular

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, sorgenfrey-line

I want to prove that lower limit topology $\Bbb R_l$ is regular and am taking the approach as follows:

Let $A$ be a closed set and $x$ a point in $\Bbb R_l$ such that $x \notin A$.
Let $a \in A$. If $a >x$, then take the open set $[a, 2a)$ containing $a$ and if $a<x$, then take the open set $[a,q)$ containing $a$ where $q$ is any rational number between $a$ and $x$.

Now if we take the union of all these open sets for all $a \in A$ and denote it by $U_A$ then clearly, $U_A \cap \{x\}= \phi$ because each individual open set is disjoint with $\{x\}$.

But now I am stuck with finding an open set containing $x$ which does not intersect with $A$.

Answer (score 4):

**Noob mathematician** has shown how you can modify your approach slightly to get the desired result. That modification can actually be carried a lot further and allow you to avoid picking nbhds of individual points of $A$. As **Noob mathematician** said, since $x\notin A$, and $A$ is closed, there is a basic open nbhd $[x,y)$ of $x$ such that $[x,y)\cap A=\varnothing$. But the set $[x,y)$ is not only open in $\Bbb R_\ell$: it is also closed, so its complement $U=\Bbb R_\ell\setminus[x,y)$ is open in $\Bbb R_\ell$. And clearly $U\supseteq A$, so $[x,y)$ and $U$ are disjoint open sets containing $x$ and $A$, respectively.

Comment: True .. I was stupid I missed this easy  observation .

Comment: @Noobmathematician: Not stupid: just thinking along the lines already established by the OP.

Comment: what an elegant proof! I missed it even while studying @Noobmathematician's answer. thank you for your answer.
But just asking out of curiosity, can we use this approach to show any other property of $\Bbb R_l$ like normality or countability?

Comment: @Singh_Gunjeet: Not really: this approach relies on the fact that we’re really working at just one point. An approach more like yours can be used to prove normality, but it’s the hard way: it’s easier to prove that the space is Lindelöf and then use the fact that a regular, Lindelöf space is normal. You can try that proof on your own, or you can read it in [Dan Ma’s Topology Blog](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/a-note-on-the-sorgenfrey-line/). As for countability properties, first countability is easy, and it’s not hard to show that the space isn’t second countable.

Comment: okay, thanks.
I know this fact that a regular, Lindelof space is normal and I completely agree with you that it's much shorter to prove normality using this fact. I have done it in my course.
again, thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Singh_Gunjeet: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is closed so you already have a basic open set containing $x$ now that open set will be of the form $[x,y)$ and $[x,y)\cap A=\phi$.

Now choose that open sets $[a,q)$ in such a way that $[a,q)\cap [x,y)=\phi$.
 This is always possible as for every $a\in A$ either $a>y$ or $a<x$. So you are done.

Comment: @Singh_Gunjeet I thing this works . If there's doubt let me know

Comment: yes, it is absolutely fine.

Comment: I was carried away by your approach and hence tried to modify it . @Brain's solution is elegant .