# Problem 17(i i ): Show $\Bbb R$ is regular

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation

[image][image]

I will try to prove $\Bbb R$ is regular

**Attempt** (edited)

Let $\Bbb R$ be defined on usual topology

Let A be closed  and  A$\subset\Bbb R$ and x$\in \Bbb R$ and x$\notin A$

So if [a,b] is closed then it’s complement U=$\Bbb R\setminus [a,b]$ is open.

By Def 3.2.1 if x$\in\Bbb R $ then x$\in U\subset \Bbb R $ s.t (a,b)$\cap A=\emptyset$

And U=(-$\infty$,a)$\cup(b,\infty$) which is the union of open sets,so open

So U $\supseteq A$ and A and
(-$\infty$,a) and (b,$\infty$)are disjoint containing x and A respectively ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Am l missing anything?

Do l have to find to subsets within (-$\infty$,a) and (b,$\infty$)

Comment: In that problem $\Bbb R$ has its usual topology, not the finite-closed topology; this is stated explicitly just before the exercises. Despite your assertion at the beginning, however, you appear to be thinking of the usual topology, not the finite-closed topology. Unfortunately, much of what you’ve written is incoherent. What is $A$? Where did $[a,b]$ come from? (And $[a,b]$ is **not** closed in the finite closed topology unless $a=b$.) Finally, you seem to think that every closed set in the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ is a closed interval: this is very far from the truth.

Comment: I did it says it right there. It is on the section after subspaces @hardmath

Comment: I first thought to use usual...When you did Z you told me to use discrete topology. I will revise it. I was using your ideas. @BrianMScott

Comment: Topology without tears @hardmath

Comment: Again that provides significant context, so in your next edit to the body of the Question you will perhaps include that title and the author.

Comment: I was using your argument in a similar proof. For p, l wanted to use neighborhood notation to show we can find some point in the designated interval.  For [a,b] see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3689918/830852 @ BrianMScott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you are supposed to assume that $\Bbb R$ has its usual topology, not the finite-closed topology (also known as the cofinite topology), and most of what you’ve written suggests that you were in fact thinking of the usual topology. For instance, an interval $[a,b]$ is not finite unless $a=b$, so in general it is **not** closed in the finite-closed topology, but it **is** closed in the usual topology. However, it is very far from being the only kind of closed set: $\Bbb Z$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$ that is not of the form $[a,b]$, as is $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$, to name just two.

Now let’s take a look at your argument. You start with a set $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ and a point $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $x\notin A$; since you’re trying to prove that $\Bbb R$ is regular, that’s a very reasonable place to start, except that you also want to assume that $A$ is closed. After that, though, things go a bit haywire. You let $p$ be a point of $A$, but why? You never mention $p$ again, so it serves absolutely no purpose.

Then you say that we can find ‘an open nbhd of $[a,b]$ of $x$ such that $[a,b]\cap A=\varnothing$’. I suspect that the first *of* wasn’t supposed to be there, and it was supposed to read ‘an open nbhd $[a,b]$ of $x$’, but $[a,b]$ isn’t open. Its complement $U=(\leftarrow,a)\cup(b,\to)$ is open in the usual topology, not the ‘closed topology’, what ever that is.

As you’ve set things up it is indeed true that $U\supseteq A$, and it is also true that $(\leftarrow,a)$ and $(b,\to)$ are disjoint, but $A$ could be a subset of either of those rays: there is no reason to think that $A\subseteq(b,\to)$. And since you apparently wanted $[a,b]$ to be a nbhd of $x$, $x$ must be in $[a,b]$, so clearly $(\leftarrow,a)$ cannot contain $x$.

Let’s go back to the beginning and start over. Let $A$ be a closed set in $\Bbb R$, and let $x\in\Bbb R\setminus A$. Then $\Bbb R\setminus A$ is an open set containing $x$, so there is an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $x\in(a,b)\subseteq\Bbb R\setminus A$. Since $x\in(a,b)$, we know that $a<x<b$, so there are $c,d\in\Bbb R$ such that $a<c<x<d<b$. Let $U=(c,d)$ and $V=(\leftarrow,a)\cup(b,\to)$; clearly $U$ and $V$ are open sets, $x\in U$, and $U\cap V=\varnothing$. I’ll leave it to you to complete the proof by showing that $A\subseteq V$.

Comment: @Homer: Yes, that’s how I defined it.

Comment: Can. I state “let p$\in $A,we find an open nbhd of p s.t  [a,b]$\cap$A=$\emptyset$ “ @BrianMScott

Comment: @Homer: That makes no sense: what is the connection between ‘an open nbhd of $p$’ and the set $[a,b]$, which isn’t open and introduces real numbers $a$ and $b$ without any explanation?

Comment: I wanted to say let p$\in (a,b)\subset $ N. s.t.. is def 3.2.1 of a open neighborhood by Morris

Comment: @Homer: What is $N$ here? (And in any case why on earth are you looking at points in $A$?)

Comment: N is neighborhood . Def 3.2.1 tells we look in open sets,right. I am looking at its complement @BrianMScott

Comment: @Homer: At this point I honestly can’t tell what you’re doing now. $N$ is a nbhd of what? How is it defined? In any case, I really think that you would be better off trying to understand and finish the proof in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: N=$\Bbb R$ Getting bogged down in terminology  @BrianMScott gonna do it soon

Comment: @Homer The proof for $\Bbb Q$ is essentially the same, except endpoints of intervals are chosen to be rational. $\Bbb Z$ has the discrete topology so there it's immediate that it's regular. The irrationals are like $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q$ again. For $\Bbb R^2$ you use rectangles of intervals as a base, so that easily generalises too, if you think about it.